# Understanding an expression involving sum notation

Tags: summation

See the following expression.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \in i} f(a_i)d_j - \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \in i} f(b_j) d_j$$

So in the first two sums, we pick a $i$, and then we sum over all $j$ that satisfy $j \in i$ (the notation itself means nothing: just that we pick certain $j$ that satisfy something for the chosen $i$).

In the second, we do something similar, however now the $f(x)$ term now depends on $j$.

Could someone explain to me why above is less than the following expression? $$ \text{'above'} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \in i} |f(a_i) - f(\eta_j)| d_j $$

It just pops straight up in a proof I'm reading, and I am not sure what's going on? something with triangle inequality, I'm guessing, but how does it all add up?

Comment: In the inequality, do you mean $b_j$ instead of $\eta_j$?

Comment: Oops. Yes. $b_j$. The eta is from a different proof on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, its basically the triangular inequality.

You can join the two summations since the range is the same, then you just use the triangular inequality as usual, since it is just a bunch of sums, the total sum must be less than or equal to the sum of the absolute value of the individual terms, since some of them can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just the triangle inequality.  In summation for that looks like
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n x_n\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^n|x_n|.$$